# Powering a compressor for an air horn

Tags: power-electronics

I am trying to build a circuit to power a compressor that blows an air horn:

[image: Airhorn schematic]

I put my DC power supply directly on the positive and negative ends of the compressor and while it does turn on, it most definitely is not generating enough air to blow one let alone two of the air horns. I don't have any air leaks. The compressor/air horn is brand new. Ramping up the power through the circuit does yield more air pressure but not nearly enough to blow the horns. Anything I'm doing wrong?

Compressor/air horn: [Zento Deals 12V DC Super Loud Dual Trumpet Air Horn Compressor Kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01GVZ77GM)

Comment: Power it from a car battery and measure the current necessary, then make you power supply capable of providing that as a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Compressors, depending on design, can draw power in a way that results in surges during the compression cycle, so you may need a power supply capable of handling much, much more than the average current. You would need an oscilloscope and a shunt to measure the current draw during the cycle.

As a wild-a** guess, I would say 20A @ 13.8VDC would be sufficient. 5A, probably not.

The problem is that your bench supply will limit almost immediately (after the output capacitor discharges) once the maximum current has been exceeded. A car battery won't do that.

Comment: that's probably it, thanks!